# Android : Issues with Retrofit 2 and GSON & JSON

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, flickr

I'm now try to parse JSON FROM this link ("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=fdac2e9676991ac53b34651adab52518&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157671978046542-6e266595ffed01f8&api_sig=58e08d365779a8f2e946a2b5320199e2")

This is what I do in my Java:

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SinglePhotoRetrofit {
@SerializedName("id")
public String id;
@SerializedName("owner")
public String owner;
@SerializedName("secret")
public String secret;
@SerializedName("server")
public String server;
@SerializedName("farm")
  public int farm;     

    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

    @SerializedName("ispublic")
    public int ispublic;

    @SerializedName("isfriend")
    public int isfriend;

    @SerializedName("isfamily")
    public int isfamily;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;     
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by karim on 8/26/16.
 */
public class PhotosRetrofit {
    @SerializedName("page")
    public int page;

    @SerializedName("pages")
    public int pages;

    @SerializedName("perpage")
    public int perpage;

    @SerializedName("total")
    public String total;

    @SerializedName("photo")
    public List<SinglePhotoRetrofit> photo;

    @SerializedName("stat")
    public String stat;

    public List<SinglePhotoRetrofit> getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(List<SinglePhotoRetrofit> photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}`
```

and here is my interface

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

import java.util.List;    
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

/**
 * Created by karim on 8/26/16.
 */
public interface HandleRetrofit {
/*
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search
&api_key=6d5c5a20d108f8f56f324394d3e2381f
&format=json
&nojsoncallback=1
&auth_token=72157672948729705-c211cbcbcac8bb30
&api_sig=bd73bb34b0f29390a80c6ffdbb376c97

 */
    @GET("rest/?")
    Call<PhotosRetrofit> Photos (
            @Query("method") String method,
            @Query("api_key") String key,
            @Query("format") String format,
            @Query("nojsoncallback") int call_back,
            @Query("auth_token") String token,
            @Query("api_sig") String sig
    );

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

and my MainActivity looks like `->`

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                /*
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search
&api_key=fdac2e9676991ac53b34651adab52518
&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
&auth_token=72157671978046542-6e266595ffed01f8
&api_sig=58e08d365779a8f2e946a2b5320199e2
 */
                final String API_KEY = "fdac2e9676991ac53b34651adab52518";
                final String METHOD = "flickr.photos.search";
                final String AUTH_TOKEN = "72157671978046542-6e266595ffed01f8";
                final String API_SIG = "58e08d365779a8f2e946a2b5320199e2";
                final String FORMAT = "json";
                final int CALL_BACK = 1;

        HandleRetrofit handleRetrofit = HandleRetrofit.retrofit.create(HandleRetrofit.class);
        Call<PhotosRetrofit> call = handleRetrofit.Photos(METHOD,API_KEY,FORMAT,CALL_BACK,AUTH_TOKEN,API_SIG);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotosRetrofit>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<PhotosRetrofit> call, Response<PhotosRetrofit> response) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photoTitle);

                        PhotosRetrofit photosRetrofit = response.body();

                        textView.setText(photosRetrofit.total+"\n");    

                        Log.w("---___---Respones","Hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                    }   

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<PhotosRetrofit> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error :"+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.w("---___--- Error ",t.getMessage());
                    }
                });    
    }
}
```

It returns null in my TextView, also I've tried more and more to retrieve different data but I've failed on that.

Comment: This question cannot presently be edited, for this reason: `"Links to ideone.com must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."`. Please edit the question.

Comment: (To clarify, please add your code _to_ the question, rather than pointing to links on a Pasteboard. The content filter is there for a reason, and is not for circumventing).

Comment: It's wired ! 
I'm prefer to add my codes into links , because It show them more clear than pasting them here  ! 

So , Why Stackoverflow enforce me on that !!

Comment: For two reasons: (1) our experience of external links is they become stale or unavailable quickly, and (2) it is easier to read inline code than it is to click on a series of external links. Remember that your question may live forever on this platform, and we want it to be readable a year from now, in case it might help other people.

Comment: Ok , It's Done now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another one class:

```
public class Photos{
  public PhotosRetrofit photos;
}
```

Update your interface:

```
 Call<Photos> Photos (...)
```

Update activity:

```
Call<Photos> call = handleRetrofit.Photos(METHOD,API_KEY,FORMAT,CALL_BACK,AUTH_TOKEN,API_SIG);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Photos>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Photos> call, Response<Photos> response) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photoTitle);
        PhotosRetrofit photosRetrofit = response.body().photos;
        textView.setText(photosRetrofit.total+"\n");
    ....
```

Comment: You are the best man in the world !! , You saved my life !!
Finalyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy, It Works !! 
But , I Wanna ask you just a little 2 questions 
1- Why you think about that it must be another model for handling PhotosRerofit (Although in JSON formant , there is only one PhotosRerofit data ) 

2- If I want to pass photos to Glide Library Using Recycler View , What Exactly I will need or in another meaning , what I will pass to Glide parameter to show my photos retrieved from Flickr-API

Comment: About model. I just may suggest you to rename Photos to PhotosRetrofit and old PhotosRetrofit to Photos. Then, you may declare Photos class as internal class of the PhotosRetroft. So, you code will look somehtin like this:
public class PhotosRetrofit{
  public class Photos{
     @SerializedName("page")
    public int page;

    @SerializedName("pages")
    public int pages;
....
  }
  public Photos photos;
}

About api.
I neer work with flickr api. But you can ready about url there:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Comment: So, final link will be look like this:

https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8162/29170354321_741f107275_z.jpg

Comment: Thank U Very much .

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Query` adds parameters to the url. This results in double parameters and the API not accepting/understanding your request. Either have an URL that doesn't contain the parameters or use `@Path`.

See in the docs under "URL Manipulation"
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

*EDIT: Think I misunderstood. You should use @Query but not include the query-paths themself*
For example:

```
@GET("rest/?&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")
Call<PhotosRetrofit> Photos (
    @Query("method") String method,
    @Query("api_key") String key,
    @Query("auth_token") String token,
    @Query("api_sig") String sig
);
```

The @Query value should be the exact value that the query-path should contain.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer 
But , Actually I were using `@Path` but logcat shows me this message 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.karim.bluecrunch/com.example.karim.bluecrunch.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "method={method}&api_key={key}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token={token}&api_sig={sig}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use `@Query` " So,I switch `@Path` to `@Query` , I would be more thankful if you show me the correct statment for using `@Path` in this case .

Comment: Sorry I believe I misunderstood. You should indeed use @Query. Except not have the url already contain the `method=`, `key=`, `auth_token=`, ect parts.

Comment: So , I'm sure about the connection to happen because , if you take a look at my MainActivity at these two line 
-  Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
- Log.w("---___---Respones","Hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");

And , Both are shown on my Logcat 

But , the problem is textView shows null text inside it ! 

Please note  , that's my first time to use Flickr-API and I'm not sure that I use it correctly or not  .

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a second look. Also what is the response you're receiving any HTTP response code?

Comment: According to what I've understand from ur answer , I've applied ur code into my interface but actually the result is the same 
Also , I've tried this
`@GET("rest/?")
    Call<PhotosRetrofit> Photos (
            @Query("method") String method,
            @Query("api_key") String key,
            @Query("format") String format,
            @Query("nojsoncallback") int call_back,
            @Query("auth_token") String token,
            @Query("api_sig") String sig
    );`
but still the same, According to HTTP response code It 's shown in Logcat as D/MainActivity: Status Code = 200

Comment: Http 200 is OK. What response are you getting?

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what do u mean by what response ?
If U mean what I'm trying to get  , the answer is I'm trying to retrieve the photo title and photos to add them on recycler View , but for now I'm trying to retrieve anything to test my Retrofit connection and JSON data parsing !

Comment: I forgot to mention that my Logcat shows a wired message "Too much ouput to process ! "

Comment: In the onSucces callback you get response. What does it contain?

Comment: No onSuccess in my code , It's onResponse and onFailure 
and , here is the code of onResponse `call.enqueue(newCallback<PhotosRetrofit>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<PhotosRetrofit> call,Response<PhotosRetrofit> response) {
 Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
 String photoRetrofit = response.body().getTotal();
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photoTitle); Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>", "Number of Data Retrieved: " + photoRetrofit);
Log.w("---___---Respones","Hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
}`
@Ruben